# Router wont clone Mac address

Tags: router, wireless-router, mac-address

I have a DX-WGRTR and in the router settings there is an option to clone WAN MAC address. When I tried to clone my computer MAC address the router reboots after 25 seconds but it automatically set the MAC address back to the original. What is preventing me from cloning the  MAC address?

Comment: Perhaps you're not entering the MAC address in precisely the form the router expects. For example, some want "XXXX-XX..." form and some want "XX:XX:XX..." form.

Comment: There is a clone button so it automatically fills in the correct format. Only problem is after the required reboot the changes don't stick and it reverts back to the original MAC.